# Redirecting embedded Hive from /var and /tmp directories

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

For my unit tests I run local spark with hive context on my laptop. On startup, it creates two directories for its temp files, one under `/var` and one under `/tmp`:

```
... INFO SessionState: Created local directory: /var/folders/h3/...
... INFO SessionState: Created HDFS directory: /tmp/hive/<username>/...
```

These folders are created by the `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState` class.

To avoid triggering some local security services, I need to redirect these directories to a different folder, e.g. `/Users/<username>/safe/`.

How can I override these default settings to open temp folders under a specified path?

Comment: I think it's the `spark.sql.warehouse.dir`. Please take a look at the parameter. You can set it using `SparkSession.config()`

Comment: @philantrovert nope :(

Answer (score 0):

In standalone Hive, `SessionState` has some configurable parameters, all settable from [`hive-site.xml`](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/common/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/conf/HiveConf.java):

```
SCRATCHDIR("hive.exec.scratchdir", "/tmp/hive",
    "HDFS root scratch dir for Hive jobs which gets created with write all (733) permission. " +
    "For each connecting user, an HDFS scratch dir: ${hive.exec.scratchdir}/<username> is created, " +
    "with ${hive.scratch.dir.permission}."),

LOCALSCRATCHDIR("hive.exec.local.scratchdir",
    "${system:java.io.tmpdir}" + File.separator + "${system:user.name}",
    "Local scratch space for Hive jobs"),

DOWNLOADED_RESOURCES_DIR("hive.downloaded.resources.dir",
    "${system:java.io.tmpdir}" + File.separator + "${hive.session.id}_resources",
    "Temporary local directory for added resources in the remote file system."),

HIVEHISTORYFILELOC("hive.querylog.location",
    "${system:java.io.tmpdir}" + File.separator + "${system:user.name}",
    "Location of Hive run time structured log file")
```

I'm not familiar with how exactly Spark embeds Hive, but I 'm sure there is a [hive-site.xml](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/test/resources/data/conf/hive-site.xml) (the one linked is test conf) and is this that controls the values for `hive.exec.scratchdir`,  `hive.exec.local.scratchdir` and the rest.